# Vb.net application not responding if using touch screen

Tags: vb.net

I have a POS application built with VB.NET.
Everything works fine but today I realize that if I use touchscreen as to trigger click event, my application will be "not responding".

When I use mouse to click, it works fine.

Anybody face this problem?

Note: using Lenovo AIO for the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem ! only to realize that I had not loaded the drivers for the touch screen.

Comment: Yes, can you confirm that the touchscreen is working correctly outside of the application? So by this, do you have drivers installed and is the operating system touch enabled?

Comment: @Basit Bulbulia : is it working correctly outside your application?

Comment: @Oscar -  Yes it is !